# Trouble creating a default desktop for new users 18.4.03

Tags: 18.04, default, adduser

How can I get default directories to show up automatically when I create a new user? I looked at messing with the /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults file by setting `Desktop = (Folder with the dir in the)` and I thought it worked but ended up with users desktops pointing to a path on the admin account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to solve the problem. It was very simple but want to post here. My confusion with the `/etc/skel` was that I thought that putting files in there would only put the files in the new users Home directory.

The solution: Create a Desktop dir in `/etc/skel` and name it Desktop. Then simply copy all of the directories you want on the new users desktop into that directory